# How render string <drupal-media> in Twig template?

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I have block in my module. I loading article type "video" and one field is "long string". Content is Media - remote video.

```
$body = $articles->get('body')->getValue();
$shortBody = $articles->get('field_video')->value;
$items[] = array(
              'title' => $articles->getTitle(),
              'text' => $body[0]['value'],
              'id' => $articles->id(),
              'path' => $alias,
              'date' => $articles->get('revision_timestamp')->value,
              'shorttext' => $shortBody
);
```

In key shorttext I have string `<drupal-media data-align="center" data-entity-type="media" data-entity-uuid .... </drupal-media>`. Template see this as string, so it dont render video file. How can I render video file from this string in Twig template?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to apply the filter `raw` to the string?

Comment: No, but this not help

Answer (score 1):

OK, my solution was this. I change field type to Media - entity.

Then I rewrite `$shortBody = $articles->get('field_video')->value;` to `$shortBody = $articles->get('field_video')->getValue();`

and in Twig file

```
{{ drupal_entity('media', item.shorttext) }}
```

This is working nicely.

Comment: That was spot on man! Thanks!